# Pull IP Address from website

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the IP Address from one website (www.website.com)
using two different methods.

On www.website.com I use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and send the IP address of www.website.com over to www.website2.com. I then use `gethostbyname("www.website.com")` on www.website2.com to search for the IP adress of www.website.com to compare them both, but for some reason they are not the same.

Why are the IP Addresses different from each other?

Comment: Are they both hosted on the same nameserver?

Comment: Yes for now, but some sites might not be.

Comment: They can be hosted on the same nameserver and server while at the same time having different IPs if they are using dedicated IPs. The nameserver is just authoritative to direct users to the proper IP.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives the IP address of the client making the HTTP request, not the server hosting the script (which is held in `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`).

Comment: @ChristianDaley — That key does not appear when I run `print_r($_SERVER)` on my server, so I wouldn't expect so.

Comment: `SERVER_ADDR` worked perfect! Thanks! Give it 8 minutes and I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This also accounts for IPs coming from `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

```
/**
 * getVisitorIP
 *
 * Gets visitor IP address
 *
 * @return string Visitor IP address
 */
public function getVisitorIP() {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];      
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```